# dynamic_rnn() and array_ops.reverse_sequence() problems

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to reverse my inputs with `array_ops.reverse_sequence()` before sending it to `dynamic_rnn()`, the inference graph can be build with no problem, but when building the training graph, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/trainer.py", line 158, in <module>
    kmer_len=args.kmer_len)
  File "/home/ubuntu/GIT/IvyMike/ivymike/base_model.py", line 193, in run_training
    train_op = model.training(loss, learning_rate)
  File "/home/ubuntu/GIT/IvyMike/ivymike/base_model.py", line 100, in training
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 190, in minimize
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 241, in compute_gradients
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py", line 481, in gradients
    in_grads = _AsList(grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_grad.py", line 307, in _ReverseSequenceGrad
    seq_lengths=seq_lengths),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1143, in reverse_sequence
    batch_dim=batch_dim, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2119, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1586, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1257, in _ReverseSequenceShape
    (batch_dim, input_shape.ndims))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  In order to help debug your code, please edit your question and post the source code that generated the errors.

Comment: This is a bug in the `tf.reverse_sequence()` implementation! I've filed a [GitHub issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480456/dynamic-rnn-and-array-ops-reverse-sequence-problems) and am working on a fix.

Comment: For some reasons I am not allowed to post my code here, but the bug occurs when I try to stack multiple layers of BLSTM using 'dynamic_rnn()' (see this related request: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1779). For the backward pass, I first reversed the input using 'array_ops.reverse_sequence()', then reversed the output using the same function. I also used feed forward layers in between the BLSTMs. 

However, with one BLSTM layer, everything is fine.  

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed at the mater in TensorFlow